# script for creating links

Tags: bash, hyperlink

I have a folder (say /data) with a set of files say: a.txt, b.bin, c.bak, d.txt, e.bin. I need to create links to those files with the exact same name (1-1 mapping) in a folder (/dataIL). That is, /dataIL should have 5 links:

```
a.txt->../data/a.txt  
b.bin->../data/b.bin  
c.bak->../data/c.bak  
d.txt->../data/d.txt  
e.bin->../data/e.bin
```

The command to create one link is:
ln -s ../data/a.txt a.txt

Wondering what script commands I can run to create for all files. Note there files with other extensions too. I just need links to all files with any extension.

I have a bash shell. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the asterisk to create symbolic links to all the files since they're in one directory:

```
ln -s data/* .
```

This assumes you would like to create links to all the files in `data`. Note also that depending on your settings this may skip files with names starting with a dot.

Comment: You don't even need to give the last parameter to `ln` -- by default it uses the current dir.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ../data -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "ln -s {} \`basename {}\`" \;
```

../data can be any directory

Comment: The only advantage to this over Adam Zalcman's approach is that it will keep working even when there are a ridiculously large number of files in the directory. For most people this is not a practical concern. I would suggest an improvement: Just exec `ln` directly, like this: `-exec ln -s {} . \;`. There's no need to specify the target file name as it will default to the source file name.